# SQL Server 'like' when joining tables (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I need to join two tables from two different database. One table is from their flight operations software and is called 'Trips' with the column 'Trip Number'. I need to join this to a table that contains invoices in their accounting software, with a column 'Invoice Number'.

The invoice number is either:

- Trip Number
- CM + [Trip Number]
- [Trip Number] + [a-Z]
- [Trip Number] + [a-Z] + [a-Z]
- [Trip Number] + [a-Z] + [a-Z] + [a-Z]
- CM + [Trip Number] + [a-Z]
- CM + [Trip Number] + [a-Z] + [a-Z]
- CM + [Trip Number] + [a-Z] + [a-Z] + [a-Z]

So the join would be [Invoice Number] = [Trip Number] OR [Invoice Number] = 'CM' + [Trip Number] OR [Invoice Number] = [Trip Number] + [a-Z] OR....

Is there a better, more concise way of doing this? I can't use [Invoice Number] like '%'+[Trip Number]+'%' or the like because that would include more than just the above matching criteria, such as it would match trip number 1000 with invoice number 10001. Is there a way of saying ~this~ + 0-3 characters in the [a-Z] set?

Comment: regex... I would filter/clean the invoice number from their data first, then join it with your data.

Comment: Why do you need a more concise way? To reduce typing? Your current version show exactly what happens and is easy to extend. The join would require a index/table scan any way so a few extra string comparisons will not affect performance.

Comment: @adrianm You are right more or less. I originally wanted to make it easier to read for future people looking at it, but that was a function of  my formatting. After formatting it properly I believe it is easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PATINDEX`, you add this to the condition

```
PATINDEX( [Trip Number]  + '[a-z][a-z][a-z]',  [Invoice Number] ) =1
```